# Как на шаблон вывести значение из словаря (Choice)

Tags: html, python, django

Короче говоря, есть у Меня в модели есть поле

```
    fuel = models.CharField(
    max_length=1,
    choices=FUEL_CHOICES,
```

Собствено тип топлива записан в `FUEL_CHOICES` который выглядит так :

```
    FUEL_CHOICES = (
    ('P', 'Бензин'),
    ('D', 'Дизель'),
    ('L', 'Газ/Бензин'),
    ('H', 'Гибрид'),
    ('E', 'Электро')
```

А вот и вопрос , как на шаблоне вывести не `Р` , а `Бензин` , то есть не ключ , а значение .
Пробовал выводить так : `Вид топлива : {{ item.vehicle.fuel }}`

Answer (score 0):

Для каждого поля из choices есть метод get_FOO_display(), где FOO - это имя поля. Этот метод возвращает «удобочитаемое» значение поля, подробнее в документации: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display